# git clean selected ignored pattern

Tags: git

Remove files:

`git clean -df`

Remove files and all ignored files:

`git clean -dfx`

Remove files except for a given pattern:

`git clean -dfe *.suo`

I want to **include** a pattern, so how could I do something like:

`git clean -dfi [Oo]bj`

Where the [Oo]bj is part of my .gitignore, so clean will not hit it. Is it possible to force a clean of a particular pattern? I certainly don't want to clean all of my ignored files, just a particular pattern.

Comment: If they're ignored files, why not just use `find` and `rm`?

Comment: or `find -delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git clean` does not have an include pattern.

You are probably better off just using a simple script

```
 find . -name '*.[Oo]bj' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to put this into a script or something, here's a command you can use:

```
git status -su | sed 's/^?? //g' | grep -i '\.obj$' | xargs rm
```